Renaming files with r library("tidyverse”)
I'm trying to rename a bunch of files in r with library("tidyverse”).
As is: Snap-551-Image Export-01_c1_ORG.tif
The bold section is a running number, starting at 01 going to 150, each number combined with _c1 and _c2
TO be: 001_551_c1_AE2315_01.tif
The first 20 files are from the same sample. Therefore, the naming for those should have the same sample number, here 001 in bold. The original number should be used at the end of the new file name.

I would very much appreciate any help on this :-) Thanks a lot & best, Andi

I don't understand why you need the tidyverse for this. I would use a list.files, gsub and file.rename. The only slightly challenging part is creating the correct regex.

Please consider including your existing code, it would provide some insights on how you planned to approach this problem and which parts proved to be challenging.

So 001 refers to the first 20 files and the next 20 should have 002? If not, where else should the sample number be derived from?

Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See this Meta and a relevant xkcd. Can you post sample data in dput format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of dput(<filenames table>). Or, if it is too big with the output of dput(head(<filenames table>, 20)).

I had a similar problems two days ago and I used file.rename plus a pattern as someone already told you. tidyverse is not the option for you issue.

This uses regular expressions (regex) to create a vector of new names based on the original names of your .tif files, then uses that vector to rename your files. As others have stated, this can be achieved using base R, but if you want a tidyverse solution, here is how to do it using the dplyr and stringr packages.
If you exclude the select() function, you will be able to see the individual steps used to create the file names e.g. the id_num columns. The three regex could be done in one, but my skills don't extend that far. Plus, using three different steps arguably makes it easier to follow if you are not familiar with regex.
It will still work even if you have multiple series numbers e.g. 551, 552 etc.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Set working directory to where tif files are stored (change to suit)
setwd("C:/folder/where/tif/files/stored")

# Create dataframe with vector of tif file names
file_list <- data.frame(old_name = list.files(pattern = "^Snap.*\\.tif$"))

# Create column with vector of new names (based on your example)
file_list <- file_list |>
  mutate(
    id_num1 = str_extract(old_name, "(?<=Snap-)[0-9]+"),
    id_num2 = str_extract(old_name, "(?<=Image Export-)[0-9]+"),
    id_num3 = str_extract(old_name, "(?<=_c)[0-9]+"),
    new_name = sprintf("%03d_%s_c%s_AE2315_%02d.tif",
                       as.integer(id_num2),
                       id_num1,
                       id_num3,
                       as.integer(id_num2))) |>
  select(old_name, new_name)

# Rename file_list
file.rename(file_list$old_name, file_list$new_name)


Maybe this simple example works for you:
# text files in current working directory
A.txt, B.txt, C.txt

# get all files with the unique extension in your cwd
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")

# rename the files by passing a vector of the new file names to the file.rename() function in the order of files in your cwd
file.rename(from = files,
            to = c("Apt.txt","Bart.txt","Dart.txt"))

# renamed files in cwd
Apt.txt, Bart.txt, Dart.txt

This is a very simple example of how to rename files in the cwd, however, but I hope it points you in the right direction.

Is this a ChatGPT answer? It surely seems so. And it doesn't address the question, where is a regex?

This is NOT a ChatGPT-generated answer. People should stop assuming that every well articulated answer posted on SO must be AI-generated. Humans are intelligent and can take their time as well!
Also, I believe the document selection pattern is clear in the answer above.
